# Rasa init cannot be executed

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

my rasa init --no-prompt is throwing some import error

```
ImportError: This version of TensorFlow Probability requires TensorFlow version >= 1.14; Detected an installation of version 1.13.2. Please upgrade TensorFlow to proceed.
```

Although when i tried to change the tensorflow version it throws the same error.

```
ImportError: This version of TensorFlow Probability requires TensorFlow version >= 1.14; Detected an installation of version 1.13.2. Please upgrade TensorFlow to proceed.
```

This is my pip freeze

```
absl-py==0.8.0
aiofiles==0.4.0
aiohttp==3.5.4
alembic==1.0.11
APScheduler==3.6.0
asn1crypto==0.24.0
astor==0.8.0
async-generator==1.10
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==19.1.0
blis==0.2.4
boto3==1.9.146
botocore==1.12.221
bz2file==0.98
cachetools==3.1.1
certifi==2019.6.16
cffi==1.12.3
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
cloudpickle==1.2.1
colorama==0.4.1
colorclass==2.2.0
coloredlogs==10.0
colorhash==1.0.2
ConfigArgParse==0.14.0
cryptography==2.7
cycler==0.10.0
cymem==2.0.2
Cython==0.29.13
decorator==4.4.0
dill==0.3.0
docopt==0.6.2
docutils==0.15.2
dopamine-rl==2.0.5
en-core-web-md==2.1.0
fakeredis==1.0.3
fbmessenger==6.0.0
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-Cors==3.0.8
future==0.17.1
gast==0.2.2
gevent==1.4.0
gin-config==0.2.1
google-api-python-client==1.7.11
google-auth==1.6.3
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-pasta==0.1.7
googleapis-common-protos==1.6.0
greenlet==0.4.15
grpcio==1.23.0
gunicorn==19.9.0
gym==0.14.0
h5py==2.9.0
httplib2==0.13.1
httptools==0.0.13
humanfriendly==4.18
idna==2.8
isodate==0.6.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
jmespath==0.9.4
jsonpickle==1.1
jsonschema==2.6.0
kafka-python==1.4.6
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.0
kfac==0.2.0
kiwisolver==1.1.0
Mako==1.1.0
Markdown==3.1.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.0.3
mattermostwrapper==2.1
mesh-tensorflow==0.0.5
mock==3.0.5
mpmath==1.1.0
multidict==4.5.2
murmurhash==1.0.2
networkx==2.3
numpy==1.16.3
oauth2client==4.1.3
object-detection==0.1
opencv-python==4.1.1.26
packaging==19.0
pika==1.0.1
Pillow==6.1.0
plac==0.9.6
preshed==2.0.1
promise==2.2.1
prompt-toolkit==2.0.9
protobuf==3.9.1
psutil==5.6.3
psycopg2-binary==2.8.2
pyasn1==0.4.7
pyasn1-modules==0.2.6
pycparser==2.19
pydot==1.4.1
pyglet==1.3.2
PyJWT==1.7.1
pykwalify==1.7.0
pymongo==3.8.0
pyparsing==2.4.2
pypng==0.0.20
pyreadline==2.1
PySocks==1.7.0
python-crfsuite==0.9.6
python-dateutil==2.8.0
python-editor==1.0.4
python-engineio==3.9.3
python-socketio==4.0.1
python-telegram-bot==11.1.0
pytz==2019.1
PyYAML==5.1.2
questionary==1.1.1
-e git+https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa.git@4d1db2a755355031eb776e05bdf102159b1ccf8c#egg=rasa
rasa-sdk==1.3.0a1
rasa-x==0.20.2
redis==3.3.5
requests==2.22.0
requests-toolbelt==0.9.1
rocketchat-API==0.6.31
rsa==4.0
ruamel.yaml==0.15.94
s3transfer==0.2.1
sanic==19.3.1
Sanic-Cors==0.9.8
sanic-jwt==1.3.1
Sanic-Plugins-Framework==0.8.2
scikit-learn==0.20.2
scipy==1.2.1
setuptools-scm==3.3.3
simplejson==3.16.0
six==1.12.0
sklearn-crfsuite==0.3.6
slackclient==1.3.1
sortedcontainers==2.1.0
spacy==2.1.4
SQLAlchemy==1.3.8
srsly==0.1.0
sympy==1.4
tabulate==0.8.3
tensor2tensor==1.14.0
tensorboard==1.14.0
tensorflow==1.14.0
tensorflow-datasets==1.2.0
tensorflow-estimator==1.14.0
tensorflow-gan==1.0.0.dev0
tensorflow-metadata==0.14.0
tensorflow-probability==0.7.0
termcolor==1.1.0
terminaltables==3.1.0
thinc==7.0.8
tqdm==4.31.0
twilio==6.26.3
tzlocal==2.0.0
uritemplate==3.0.0
urllib3==1.25.3
wasabi==0.2.2
wcwidth==0.1.7
webexteamssdk==1.1.1
websocket-client==0.54.0
websockets==6.0
Werkzeug==0.15.5
wrapt==1.11.2
yarl==1.3.0
```

In my environment the version of tensorflow is 1.14 but i dont know why is it throwing the same error.there was some initial error with Rasa sdk version,can someone guide me through right direction please.

Comment: Try `python -c "import tensorflow; tenosrflow.__version__"` to see what version loads.

Answer (score 1):

I think your versions of libraries are outdated and not compatible with tenserflow. Unless you want exact versions of those libraries you can just install the latest version of it without specify the version of it. If you want those version only try uninstall tenserflow and re-install with a version specified.